# Unable to connect my NiFi Registry on HTTPS - Your connection isn't private

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, apache-nifi, self-signed

I have setup NiFi Registry on my Linux ubuntu machine.

I used this command to generate certificates.

```
sudo ./tls-toolkit.sh standalone -n "xx.xx.xx.xx" -C "CN=sys_admin, OU=NIFI" -o target
```

xx.xx.xx.xx is my Host IP

the above command generate following folder and certificates

```
xx.xx.xx.xx (folder)
CN=sys_admin_OU=NIFI.p12
CN=sys_admin_OU=NIFI.password
nifi-cert.pem
nifi-key.key
```

xx.xx.xx.xx folder has following files:

```
keystore.jks
nifi.properties
truststore.jks
```

I copy keystore.jks and truststore.jks in /opt/nifi-registry/conf directory

I also copy keystorepasswd, truststorepasswd and keypasswd values from nifi-properties file and paste it in nifi-registry-properties. As seen below:

```
# security properties #

nifi.registry.security.autoreload.interval=10 secs
nifi.registry.security.keystore=./conf/keystore.jks
nifi.registry.security.keystoreType=jks
nifi.registry.security.keystorePasswd=5Nj2vk8ElO3KtSPrJnGBIO/qJcoZmccx1/0oRSQws/Q
nifi.registry.security.keyPasswd=5Nj2vk8ElO3KtSPrJnGBIO/qhsgbmah75f0oRSQws/Q
nifi.registry.security.truststore=./conf/truststore.jks
nifi.registry.security.truststoreType=jks
nifi.registry.security.truststorePasswd=iLUegD3fUzshndhb45djh45enzOdf54d5sbgdCO21es
nifi.registry.security.needClientAuth=
nifi.registry.security.authorizers.configuration.file=./conf/authorizers.xml
nifi.registry.security.authorizer=managed-authorizer
nifi.registry.security.identity.providers.configuration.file=./conf/identity-providers.xml
nifi.registry.security.identity.provider=
```

[enter image description here][1]

I also make modififications in Authorizers.xml file contents below.

```
    <userGroupProvider>
        <identifier>file-user-group-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.registry.security.authorization.file.FileUserGroupProvider</class>
        <property name="Users File">./conf/users.xml</property>
        <property name="Initial User Identity 1">CN=sys_admin, OU=NIFI</property>
    </userGroupProvider>
```

```
    <accessPolicyProvider>
        <identifier>file-access-policy-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.registry.security.authorization.file.FileAccessPolicyProvider</class>
        <property name="User Group Provider">file-user-group-provider</property>
        <property name="Authorizations File">./conf/authorizations.xml</property>
        <property name="Initial Admin Identity">CN=sys_admin, OU=NIFI</property>
        <property name="NiFi Group Name"></property>

        <!--<property name="NiFi Identity 1"></property>-->
    </accessPolicyProvider>
```

then after restart my NiFi-Registry I try to access it.

https://hostIP:8443/nifi-registry

My browser says:

```
**Your connection isn't private**
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from xx.xx.xx.xx (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).

NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

This server couldn't prove that it's xx.xx.xx.xx; its security certificate is not trusted by your computer's operating system. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
```

I have also added the certificate in Trusted root certificate but I am still getting this.
Can someone help?

Comment: This issue has been resolved. I created the certificate using the hostname of my VM instead of IP address and that works for me.


sudo ./tls-toolkit.sh standalone -n "myhostname" -C "CN=sys_admin, OU=NIFI" -o target